# xquery error library modules cannot be evaluated or no namespace declared

Tags: xquery

When I deploy modules in JBoss, I'm getting errors:

> Library modules cannot be evaluated.
>
> Function 'hello' is in reserved namespace.
>
> No namespace declared for 'm:hello'.

```
xquery version "3.0" encoding "utf-8";
import module namespace m = 'http://basex.org/modules/Hello' at     'HelloWorld2.xq';
m:hello("Universe")
```

I already had `Helloworld2.xq` file in my `src/main/resources`. It is not recognizing or showing as duplicate namespace. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Am new to Xquery, need to reuse the existing query in our web application which is running under Jboss. How to configure the Xquery i.e. engine and  importing the existing xquery files/ functions? Trying with BaseX, XQJ, and other implementation, seems not going in the right way, so.... Thanks in advance for kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are the owner of the domain "basex.org", you should probably use a different namespace for functions you write.  Create a namespace in a part of URI space for which you actually do have some naming rights.  That should clear at least the second error.

What relative URI to use to find a module appears to be a frequent source of confusion; if you are using BaseX, be sure to read the BaseX documentation on configuring BaseX via web.xml.